# How redirect to mobile website version in Facebook in-app browser with htaccess

Tags: facebook, .htaccess, redirect, mobile

I'm trying to redirect all website visitors with mobile browsers to a mobile version of the website with .htaccess. That works great everywhere, except for facebook's in-app browser. How can I force facebook's in-app browser redirect to a mobile version of the website? 
Thanks.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/m
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} "text/vnd.wap.wml¦application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml" [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "acs|alav|alca|amoi|audi|aste|benq|blac|blaz|brew|cell|cldc|cmd-" [NC,OR]
```

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "FB_IAB|FBAN|FBAV" [NC,OR]` - seem doesn't work

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "dang|doco|erics|hipt|inno|ipaq|java|jigs|kddi|keji|leno|lg-c|lg-d|lg-g|lge-" [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "maui|maxo|midp|mits|mmef|mobi|mot-|moto|mwbp|nec-|newt|noki|opwv" [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "palm|pana|pant|pdxg|phil|pluc|port|prox|qtek|qwap|sage|sams|sany" [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "sch-|sec-|send|seri|sgh-|shar|sie-|siem|smal|smar|sony|sph-|symb|t-mo" [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "teli|tim-|tsm-|upg1|upsi|vk-v|voda|w3cs|wap-|wapa|wapi" [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "wapp|wapr|webc|winw|winw|xda|xda-" [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "up.browser|up.link|windowssce|iemobile|mini|mmp" [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "symbian|midp|wap|phone|pocket|android|mobile|pda|psp" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/m/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Which operating system are you testing on? You should test on Android and iOS to be sure. The only explanation that comes to mind, here, is that the agent string isn't actually being set. As far as I can tell, your new condition is correct. You could probably just check for `FB_IAB`, though, as that seems to *always* be included.

Comment: I'm testing on **Android**. Here is a line from website log `"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5 Build/MMB29Q; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/48.0.2564.106 Mobile Safari/537.36 [FB_IAB/FB4A;FBAV/63.0.0.37.81;]"` So the agent is set as I understand. Any ideas? @MikeRockett

Comment: Sorry, no ideas... Seems weird...

Comment: Seems FB in-app browser doesn't follow rules from .htaccess at all.

Comment: Well the browser doesn't see those rules at all - that's the server's job. Point here is that the server is not picking up on the FB_IAB that is, according to you/your records, being sent by the browser.